# Weak, strong and uniform convergence of operator on $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lebesgue-measure, uniform-convergence, weak-convergence

> For every $a \in \mathbb{R}^d$, let $T_a(f)(x) = f(x-a), \forall f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^d$. Prove that $T_a$ is a linear isometry of space $L^p$ on itself. Find $\lim_{a\to 0} T_a$ if it exists (uniform, strong, and weak). Does the result depend on $1 \leq p \leq \infty$?

I have proved the first part,
$$ ||T_a(f)|| = \left(\int_{R^d}|f(x-a)|^p dm_d(x)\right)^{1/p} = \left(\int_{R^d}|f(x)|^p dm_d(x)\right)^{1/p} = ||f||, $$
because of the invariance of the Lebesgue measure to translation and central symmetry. But I don't know what to do with the rest. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Strong convergence is a standard result. You can find it in Rudin's RCA. Uniform convergence fails: look at characteristic functions of intervals.

Comment: I do not see here what is $lim_{a\to 0} T_a$, I see only that $\lim_{a\to 0} T_a(f) = f$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Strong convergence means that for each $f$, $T_af \rightarrow T_0f$ in $L^p$. This is obvious since $f(x-a) \rightarrow f(x) \in L^p$.
2. Strong convergence implies weak convergence. So $T_a$ also converges weakly to $T_0$.
3. Norm convergence fails. Consider $||T_a - T_0|| = sup_{||f||=1} ||T_a(f) - T_0(f)||$. However, we can choose $f$ to be a function that is supported in $B_a/2(0)$. Then $f(x)$ and $f(x-a)$ has disjoint support and $||T_a(f) - T_0(f)|| > ||f||$.